# PHP exec() won't abort when running 'pdf2swf -Q 10'

Tags: php, exec, pdf2swf

I have a pdf file that makes the `pdf2swf` tool to run forever. when running the following command manually :

```
pdf2swf -Q 10 test.pdf
```

The script aborts after 10 seconds becouse of the `-Q 10` flag, but when running the same command using php the script runs forever. I've tried using `shell_exec()` ,`exec()` and [passthru()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) and all of them ignored the `-Q` flag.

Has anyone encontered anything like this with `pdf2swf` tool or with any other PHP `exec` ?

**EDIT**

when I run it manually

```
php -r "exec('pdf2swf -Q 10 test.pdf');"
```

It aborts after 10 seconds, but when running as a deamon, again, it won't abort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried same command in my test project and it worked fine with no issues, please find my code as -

> $out = exec("pdf2swf font_example.pdf -o varun.swf", $rest);

Comment: the command works for me normally. I have an issue with specific pdf file that cause the process to get stuck. The `-Q` parameter specifies a time out for the scripts. If i run it manually,  the script aborts after 10 seconds. when running in the php file, the script runs forever.

Comment: Can you please check if you have used some fonts which requires fonts folder as an argument, or if it is possible for you to provide me pdf will be great to identify the issue

Comment: sorry i can't, the pdf is not mine. the issue is more general. how can i make the  pdf2swf  to work with `-Q` when running trough php?